# objective c- adding few subviews to a UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, subviews

I have a UITableView that displays images, but I want some text to be displayed above and under every image.

when I add text it's being displayed in the center behind the image.

how can I programmatically control the position of subviews in my cell ? 
(the number of cell changes during the program at runtime)

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

inside cellForRowAtIndexPath add your text as subviews (e.g. x= 10, y = 20, width = 200, height = 100) :

```
myText = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 20, 200, 100)];
myText.text = @" some text here";
[self addSubview:myText];
```

to bring the text to the front:

```
[self bringSubviewToFront:myText];
```

Answer (score 1):

I would create a custom `UITableViewCell` to be honest. Subclass it and add the views you want to its `contentView` in its initialiser, then set it up as you wish for each cell in your table view data source.

Comment: as for now I'm not using a custom cell, but I will may change it in the close future. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should have mentioned if you are using a custom cell or not. in case it's the built-in cell that you are using, if you don't like the way it looks you should create a custom cell. see http://www.icodeblog.com/2009/05/24/custom-uitableviewcell-using-interface-builder/

If you allready use a custom cell, my guess is that you didn't implement correctly the method

```
heightForRowAtIndexPath:
```

please check if a fix is needed...